# My render is black and all of the fixes I have seen do not work

Tags: modeling, rendering, cycles-render-engine, objects

[image]I am following Blender Guru's donut tutorial on Youtube, and it was working fine until I started doing the coffee. Now, whenever I go into the render viewport the screen is completely black. Whenever I hide the donut and only render the coffee it works fine. What is the problem? None of the fixes I have found have worked.

Comment: please share the file

Comment: Do you have any lights in the scene? Are they hidden, or visible?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A7zx71dbOqJqn1GejYZ1FoE4L8sQCIh0/view?usp=sharing    And yes there is a light in the scene. Whenever I hide the donut the coffee and plate render just fine. Also figured out that it is the donut specifically and not the icing or sprinkles.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the donut - it's the material you are using. Whenever I choose other material the scene renders just fine, but with material nomber 3 and 6 everything goes black. 
It has to do something with the nodes you are using because when "Use nodes" is checked - it's black and when it's not checked it's normal.

[image]
[image]

My advice is not to use these materials - make a new one. You can even make the same nodes but don't capy and paste them - folow Andrew's tutorial.

Comment: Thanks! This worked.